# how to load a stack of images on matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I have 170 png images in a folder.
I want to load and store them in a matrix/array/cell array, so that i can easily access and modify them but I'm stuck at the very beginning.
How can I do it? Which is the best structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are all the same size, in the folder containing the images:

```
list=dir('*.png'); % read all the .pngs in your folder

Image1=imread(list(1).name); % read the first image to calculate the dimentions of your stack
ImSize=size(Image1)

ImageStack=zeros(ImSize(1),ImSize(2),length(list)); % preallocate your stack with zeros


for ii=1:length(list)

    Image=imread(list(ii).name
    ImageStack(:,:,ii)=rgb2gray(Image); % copy an image in each step of the third dimsion of your stack 
end
```

If you need the color information just add another dimension to `ImageStack` and forget the `rgb2gray()`. Hope that helps!

Comment: And what if I have images of different size? Should I use cell arrays?

Comment: That depends on how you want to process them afterwards: the cell array is a possibility, but if you want to avoid that, you can also calculate the size of `Image` in every iteration and then `ImageStack(1:ImSize(1),1:ImSize(2),ii)=rgb2gray(Image); ` but then you'll have the images padded with zeroes, and will have to calculate the size of  `ImageStack` in another loop...

Comment: Ok! I got that! Thank you for helping, it's very helpful!